# CREAR INNER JOIN MULTIPLE

Tags: sql, select, join

hace días vengo rompiéndome la cabeza.... no logro el resultado esperado.

Tengo una tabla "socio de negocio" y desde ella se relacionan una tabla "ventas" y otra tabla "ventas detalle".

hasta ahí todo bien..

Desde la tabla "socio de negocio" también se relacionan "créditos" y "créditos detalle".

El tema es que la totalidad de las cuentas están en la tabla clientes y los datos a SUMAR en ventas/créditos "detalle".
Necesito combinar ambas tablas en una sola consulta SELECT

Cuando realizo los JOIN, se duplican valores.
Esto es lo que estoy haciendo:

```
SELECT SUM(CD.Price*CD.Quantity),SUM(FD.Price*FD.Quantity)AS TN
FROM SAP_Socio_Negocio S
LEFT JOIN SAP_Facturas_Ventas F ON S.CardCode=F.CardCode 
INNER JOIN SAP_Facturas_Ventas_Detalle FD ON F.DocEntry=FD.DocEntry 
LEFT JOIN SAP_Creditos_Ventas C ON S.CardCode=C.CardCode
INNER JOIN SAP_Creditos_Ventas_Detalle CD ON C.DocEntry=CD.DocEntry
```

**si ejecuto solo una parte de la consulta, el resultado es correcto:**

```
SELECT SUM(FD.Price*FD.Quantity)AS TN 
FROM SAP_Socio_Negocio S
LEFT JOIN SAP_Facturas_Ventas F ON S.CardCode=F.CardCode 
INNER JOIN SAP_Facturas_Ventas_Detalle FD ON F.DocEntry=FD.DocEntry
```

¿alguna idea?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y no hay relaciones multiples etre esas tablas?

Comment: yo creo que necesitamos conocer las estructuras de tus tablas y ejemplos de como viene la info y como deseas obtenerla, por que así con la consulta es muy complicado simularlo.

Answer (score 0):

la solución vino por este lado y se ejecutó correctamente:

```
WITH 

INGRESO AS (
SELECT S.CardCode , SUM(FD.Price*FD.Quantity)AS TN 
FROM SAP_Socio_Negocio S
LEFT JOIN SAP_Facturas_Ventas F ON S.CardCode=F.CardCode 
INNER JOIN SAP_Facturas_Ventas_Detalle FD ON F.DocEntry=FD.DocEntry 
GROUP BY S.CardCode),

GASTO AS (
SELECT S.CardCode, SUM(CD.Price*CD.Quantity)TN 
FROM SAP_Socio_Negocio S
LEFT JOIN SAP_Creditos_Ventas C ON S.CardCode=C.CardCode
INNER JOIN SAP_Creditos_Ventas_Detalle CD ON C.DocEntry=CD.DocEntry
GROUP BY S.CardCode)

SELECT I.CardCode, (I.TN+ G.TN) AS TN
FROM INGRESO I
FULL JOIN GASTO G ON I.CardCode =G.CardCode
```